# JPA solution for crossed columns of two composite FK

Tags: jpa

I have one table "A" with a three-fields(a1,a2,a3) composite PK, and two of them(a1,a2) are a composite FK to another table "B", so I am using two @Embeddable classes to achieve this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private APk aPk;

    @MapsId(aPartPk)
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "a1")
    @JoinColumn(name = "a2")
    private B b;

    '''other columns'''

}

@Embeddable
public class APk implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private APartPk aPartPk;

    private String a3;
}

@Embeddable
public class APartPk implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String a1;

    private String a2;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private APartPk aPartPk;

    '''other columns'''

}
```

But now I have a new requirement that I need to make another two fields(a1,a3) as another composite FK and refer them to table C, is there a solution to do this? Any comments will be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to answer my own question here -

To make another two fields(a1,a3) as another composite FK and refer them to table C, just add these codes:

```
@MapsId(aPk)     -----------------------------> use the whole PK as the @MapsId
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "a1")
@JoinColumn(name = "a3")
private C c;
```